# What are the new unlockables in The Dark World?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

So far, I've noticed that all the stages, archers and variants seem to be unlocked at the start. Is there anything to unlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Dark Gauntlet* stage is unlockable: Defeat the prior 4 stages in Dark World Co-op.

That's what I've seen so far.